# How to get dataset size in sas enterprise guide log

Tags: sql, sas

```
Data xyz:
Set xyz;
Run;
```

The size of the dataset is 1.2 gb and I want to be display that size in the SAS log file, as well as at execution time. I'd like the same solution for a sql proc as well. I tried using options in SAS, but that doesn't serve my need.

Comment: I don't know that there's any option to do that. You could probably write a custom macro to do it whenever RUN is present, it could return the size of the last data set created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to try using &syslast, dictionary.tables filesize and format SIZEKMG. which adjusts per size of table whether it is kilobytes, megabytes or gigabytes and build a small macro and use it after table creation.

```
 %macro size;
   proc sql noprint;
   select 
   Filesize  format=SIZEKMG. into :val
   from dictionary.tables
   where upcase(cats(libname,'.',memname))= "&syslast"  ;
   %put Filesize of %left(&syslast) is &val;
  run;
 %mend;

 data class;
   set sashelp.class;
  run;

  %size;
```

This gives result as

```
    Filesize of WORK.CLASS is  128KB
```

Comment: any possibilities using dataset

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question

Comment: question is if i create any dataset . iwant to capture its data size like if i create dataset abc so it should display in log as datasize is 10mb(varies upon datasize)

Comment: ya, it pretty much does that

Comment: Thanks Kiran,can we implement this code for each data set creation .means if I create xyz dataset it should automatically show dataset size in log same for next dataset and so on . Like it show size on each dataset creation

Comment: &syslast captures last dataset you have created. so this code will give size of last dataset created.

Comment: So which thing should I run first ..can I set this code in precode of sas eg